# Eclipse behaves weird when generating javadoc comments for methods having annotations specified

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, comments, javadoc

I have an EJB project where I am adding JavaDOC comments for every method now it was not done earlier during development and I am doing it now. The problem that I am facing is related to getting those method arguments populated automatically in JavaDoc comment.

When annotations are specified JavaDoc do not populate method parameters in comments when you type in "/**" and hit enter, if there is no annotation it works well. But this is very annoying as we can't specify all parameters manually in JavaDoc method comments. Basically it adds an overhead.

Now it was working yesterday but not today when I switch back to a class when there is no annotations on any method it works perfect again.

Even removing annotations from method and trying afterwords do not work.

I did restart IDE few times, I have Eclipse JUNO (4.2) with OEPE tools installed for Java EE.

**Edit:**
Basically when I press Javadoc comment shortcut it gives me following comment instead of nicely formatted parameters in the list.

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see <project>.<modulegroup>.<module>.<BeanClassName>#<methodName>(java.lang.String)
 */
```

Any clue about this issue?